# Changing a variable name affects the code behavior

Tags: python, selenium, process, multiprocessing, terminate

When I run this code, one of the selenium windows is not closed

```
import multiprocessing

from selenium import webdriver


class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def run(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com')


processes = []
for i in range(2):
    worker = Worker()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker.run)
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)

for any_name in processes:
    any_name.terminate()
```

But if I change variable name from `any_name` to `worker`, then all selenium windows are closed. Why is this happening?

PS version: python 3.7, chromedriver 83, selenium 3.141.0

Comment: Huh, this reproduces for me, too. I can't explain why, but it will only close both windows if the variable name you use for the final `for` loop is the same one you assign `Worker` to. E.g. if you change `worker = Worker()` to `blah = Worker()`, you have to change `any_name` to `blah` for the windows to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser closing behavior depends on the `__del__` method of `selenium.webdriver.common.service.Service` to make the browser Windows exit, and `__del__` will only be called when there are no more references to your `WebDriver` instances. Here is the implementation of `Service.__del__`:

```py
    def __del__(self):
        # `subprocess.Popen` doesn't send signal on `__del__`;
        # so we attempt to close the launched process when `__del__`
        # is triggered.
        try:
            self.stop()
        except Exception:
            pass
```

The `stop()` method shuts everything down.

Now, the reason the variable naming matters is that it effects whether or not there are any references to a `WebDriver` when your program exits. When your first for loop completes, `worker` is still in-scope, which holds a reference to the second `Worker` you created, which holds a reference to the `WebDriver`. That keeps it in scope when your main program completes, which means `__del__` is never called, and the browser window doesn't close.

However, when you re-use `worker` for the second for loop, it means the reference to the second `Worker` is no longer held, which means there are no references to `WebDriver` in-memory, which means `__del__` will be called and the window will close. You can confirm this behavior by explicitly adding `worker = None` outside of the first for loop. With that change, both browser windows always exit, no matter what variable name you use in the second loop.